# Questions regarding Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have few questions regarding Crystal reports:

1. Do I need to have some kind of license to install Crystal reports on Webserver?
2. Do I need to have Dedicated server to host an application which uses crystal reports?
   Or can shared hosting work?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this link.

http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/index?rid=/library/uuid/70bd6328-4128-2d10-7882-d7b95418dbaa

You only need a dedicated server if you want to use the Crystal Enterprise, or whatever they call it these days

Simon

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. As I see the documentation, Page 9 of PDF, can you please let me know how Server Application (External Deployment) would differ from Commerical Hosting Service (External Deployment)?